# Rails 6 application.js Functions Not Found

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am just testing things out in a Rails 6 app and if I put a function in the app/javascript/packs/application.js file I get an Uncaught ReferenceError:  is not defined error.

If I put the following code in my html.erb file:

```
<%= button_tag "Test", class: 'btn btn-primary', onClick: 'test_func()' %>
...
<script>
  function test_func() {
    console.log("test works");
  }
</script>
```

It works as it should.  But if I put the same code inside the app/javascript/packs/application.js file, then I get the uncaught reference error.  The function should be there because if I look through the packs/js/application*.js file I can find the following:

```
/***/ "./app/javascript/packs/application.js":
/*!*********************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/javascript/packs/application.js ***!
  \*********************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
__webpack_require__(/*! bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap */ "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js");

__webpack_require__(/*! @rails/ujs */ "./node_modules/@rails/ujs/lib/assets/compiled/rails-ujs.js").start();

__webpack_require__(/*! turbolinks */ "./node_modules/turbolinks/dist/turbolinks.js").start();

__webpack_require__(/*! @rails/activestorage */ "./node_modules/@rails/activestorage/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.js").start();

__webpack_require__(/*! channels */ "./app/javascript/channels/index.js"); // Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)


function test_func() {
  console.log("test works");
}

/***/ })
```

So I'm not sure what the problem could be.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

I figured out a workaround to solve this problem.  In the `app/javascriipts/packs/application.js` file, instead of declaring the function as:

```
function test_func() {
  console.log("test works");
}
```

Declare the function like this:

```
window.test_func = function() {
  console.log("test works);
}
```

And the function will now be globally available from the html.erb files.

Comment: Look closer--it's in a function. How are you managing your imports and exports?

Comment: I noticed it was in a function, but didn't think that was wrong because all the other files compiled by webpacker seem to have the functions within a function.  Also I don't think I'm importing/exporting anything.  I didn't have to do either of those in Rails 5 (before webpacker was used) so I assumed I could do the same things.  I guess I was wrong though.

Comment: It isn't wrong--but it's not in scope outside today function because basic JavaScript scoping rules. You'll probably want to do a modern js tutorial and read the rails docs for the new pipeline.